# Odd Behavior with .NET Routing

Tags: javascript, vb.net, url-routing

I am using Routing in a VB.Net Forms project.

The page URLS are either /Topic (by itself) or /Topic/SubTopic

I load a JavaScript file in the aspx page.

When I call the page as just /Topic (e.g., http://server.com:21166/Fruit) the JavaScript file loads just fine, but when I call it as /Topic/SubTopic (e.g., http://server.com:21166/Fruit/Banana) the JavaScript file does not load.

Here are my Routing entries:

```
    routes.Ignore("{*allaxd}", New With {.allaxd = ".*\.axd(/.*)?"})
    routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", New With {.alljs = ".*\.js(/.*)?"})
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "Action/{Action}", "~/AJAXResponder.aspx")
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{TopicName}", "~/Default.aspx")
    routes.MapPageRoute("", "{TopicName}/{SubTopicName}", "~/Default.aspx")
```

Comment: This is usually caused by relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

I was sending AJAX queries to Action/{Action} and needed a preceeding slash: /Action/{Action}

This solved the issue.